# Can choosing different free variables alter the solution of a linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following system:

x + 2y - 3z = 1....(1)

```
y - 2z = 2.....(2)

2y - 4z = 4....(3)
```

Here the third equation can be eliminated as it is a multiple of the second equation and the echelon form of the above system will be:

x + 2y - 3z = 1.....(1)

```
y  - 2z = 2.....(2)
```

The echelon form has two equations in three unknowns, so there is one free variable. Suppose I choose z as a free variable. I get y = 2 + 2z...(3) and x = -3 - z....(4) Since there is one free variable, the solution space will be a line (Am I right?) From (3) and (4), we get y = - 2x - 4 to be the line of solutions.

Now suppose I choose y as a free variable. Now I will have x = - 2 - y/2 and z = y/2 - 1. Clearly, here the solution line will be in xz plane whereas the solution line above is in XY plane. I do not understand what is going on here. Why do these solution lines depend on the choice of the free variable? Aren't the terms pivot variables and free variables just computational conventions? I do understand why the solution space is a line (and hence infinite solutions). But why two different lines?

I think I am failing to understand these concepts perfectly. Please help me out here. Thanks.

Comment: While $y = - 2x - 4$ must hold for that line of solutions, it is not enough to describe that line. You still need the $z$ coordinate for each point. It's not in the XY plane, it's in a three-dimensional space. Try drawing the two solutions, and see how they compare!

Comment: Do you mean to say that y = -2x-4 and the other equation are actually planes which will intersect at the line of solutions?

Comment: Yes, you can see it that way.

Answer (score 1):

$$a=\{t,-2 t-4,-t-3\};\;b=\left\{-\frac{u}{2}-2,u,\frac{u}{2}-1\right\};\;c=\{-s-3,2 s+2,s\}$$
Are three different parametrization of the same line.

To prove this, note that the direction vectors are parallel
$$\vec{a}=\{1,-2 ,-1\};\;\vec{b}=\left\{-\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{1}{2}\right\};\;\vec{c}=\{-1,2 ,1\}$$
indeed $\vec{c}=-\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}=-\frac{1}{2}\vec{a}$

Furthermore they pass through the point $(0,-4,-3)$.

Line $a$ for $t=0$, line $b$ for $u=-4$ and line $c$ for $s=-3$.

Whatever variable we choose to let "free" the result is always that line.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. This helped. But can you please point out the errors in my understanding? How do I compare your answer with my understanding that the line of solutions is actually the intersection of the two planes which are obtained by choosing z freely, at first and then y?

Comment: @ak47 You wrote that leaving $y$ as free variable we have $x = - 2 - y/2$ and $z = y/2 - 1$ while I get $x=1 - 2 y + 3 z$ and $z= y/2-1$ (from equations (1) and (2). This gives the line $x = -2 - t/2, y = t, z = -1 + t/2$ parallel to $\vec{b}$ of my answer. Your result is not even a line. It's the plane $x+z+3=0$

Comment: you have pointed out that what I obtain is not a line but a plane. So what do  I make of it? I am having some trouble in understanding the geometric consequence of free variables.

Comment: @ak47 A plane has TWO free variables like in the system $$\{x+y+z=1,2 x+2 y+2 z=2,3 x+3 y+3 z=3\}$$. The result is $x+y+z=1$ which is the equation of a plane. In the system  $$\{x+y+z=1,2 x+2 y+2 z=2,x+y-z=0\}$$ the solutions are on a line, the intersection of the planes $x+y+z=1$ and $x+y-z=0$ whose parametric equation is $\{2 t,1-2 t,1\}$ with ONE free parameter. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you :) This helped